# Regex: match only string C that is in between string A and string B

Tags: bash, shell, sed, jq

How can I write a regex in a shell script that would target only the targeted substring between two given values? Give the example

```
https://www.stackoverflow.com
```

How can I match only the ":" in between "https" and "//".
If possible please also explain the approach.

The context is that I need to prepare a file that would fetch a config from the server and append it to the .env file. The response comes as JSON

```
{
  "GRAPHQL_URL": "https://someurl/xyz",
  "PUBLIC_TOKEN": "skml2JdJyOcrVdfEJ3Bj1bs472wY8aSyprO2DsZbHIiBRqEIPBNg9S7yXBbYkndX2Lk8UuHoZ9JPdJEWaiqlIyGdwU6O5",
  "SUPER_SECRET": "MY_SUPER_SECRET"
}
```

so I need to adjust it to the `.env` syntax. What I managed to do this far is

```
#!/bin/bash
CURL_RESPONSE="$(curl -s url)"

cat <<< ${CURL_RESPONSE} | jq -r '.property.source' | sed -r 's/:/=/g;s/[^a-zA-Z0-9=:_/-]//g' > .env.test
```

so basically I fetch the data, then extract the key I am after with `jq`, and then I use `sed` to first replace all ":" to "=" and after that I remove all the quotations and semicolons and white spaces that comes from JSON and leave some characters that are necessary.

I am almost there but the problem is that now my graphql url (and only other) would look like so

```
https=//someurl/xyz
```

so I need to replace this = that is in between https and // back with the colon.

Thank you very much @Nic3500 for the response, not sure why but I get error saying that

```
sed: 1: "s/:/=/g;s#https\(.*\)// ...": \1 not defined in the RE
```

I searched SO and it seems that it should work since the brackets are escaped and I use `-r` flag (tried `-E` but no difference) and I don't know how to apply it. To be honest I assume that the replacement block is this part

```
#\1#
```

so how can I let this know to what character should it be replaced?

This is how I tried to use it

```
#!/bin/bash
CURL_RESPONSE="$(curl -s url)"

cat <<< ${CURL_RESPONSE} | jq -r '.property.source' | sed -r 's/:/=/g;s#https\(.*\)//.*#\1#;s/[^a-zA-Z0-9=:_/-]//g' > .env.test
```

Hope with this context you would be able to help me.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with the match?

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Take a look at `awk`, use `https` and `/` as field separators and output second field.

Comment: Which shell are you using? bash or zsh?

Comment: Your examples were all Bash and I see no indication that this would be related in any way to [tag:zsh] so I removed that tag. Going forward, please don't spam unrelated tags.

Comment: Nic's regex is working fine, the problem seems to be that you are applying `-r` blindly without understanding how it changes the regex semantics. If you want to use `-r` or `-E` (they are basically synonyms, but this is a non-standard option so different `sed` implementations ended up using different option letters for this functionality) you need to remove the backslashes from `\(` and `\)` but there will probably also be other things you need to change.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "https://www.stackoverflow.com" | sed 's#https\(.*\)//.*#\1#'
:
```

- `sed` operator s/regexp/replacement/
- regexp: `https\(.*)//.*`.  So "https" followed by something (`.*`), followed by "//", followed by anything else `.*`
- the parenthesis are back slashed since they are not part of the pattern.  They are used to group a part of the regex for the replacement part of the `s###` operator.
- replacement: \1, means the first group found in the regex `\(.*\)`
- I used `s###`, but the usual form is `s///`.  Any character can take the place of the `/` with the `s` operator.  I used `#` as using `/` would have been confusing since you use `/` in the url.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `sed` substitutions are terribly imprecise. Anyway, you want to do it in `jq` instead, where you have more control over which parts you are substituting, and avoid spawning a separate process for something `jq` quite easily does natively in the first place.

```
curl -s url |
jq -r '.property.source | to_entries[] |
  "\(.key)=\"\(.value\)\""' > .env.test
```

Tangentially, capturing the output of `curl` into a variable just so you can immediately `cat` it once to standard output is just a waste of memory.